# Which SageOne API country to choose?

Tags: sage-one

I work on a SageOne Api application for France based companies. When I take a look at the SageOne documentation it appears that there are different requirements depending on the country. However I cannot find an API documentation for France only.

Does someone know how to know which SageOne API documentation I need to follow for France?

Comment: As of today, there is no public API for Sage One France. You could try and guess the URLs (from the URLs of other countries), but at your own risk. There are rumors of a new and public API coming in January 2017, but then they are only rumors.

Comment: still nice to hear. I asked the developer team in late 2015 about a France API and I understood it was not planned but "it is a possibility for the future that there will be a more global API available". Hoping it's coming soon I really need to automate more of my accounting.

Comment: The API for France is now available. The documentation can be found here: https://developer.columbus.sage.com/docs#/fr/sageone/accounts

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments.

After contacting Sage One support it appears that there is no API for french based Sage One accounts yet.